# Docker installing multiple versions of cuda on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: docker, cuda, ubuntu-16.04

firstly, I'm still beginner in docker.
I need to run multiple version of TensorFlow and each version requires a specific cuda version.
my host operating system is ubuntu 16.04
I need to have multiple versions of cuda on my OS since I'm working on multiple projects each requires a different versions of cuda. I tried to use conda and virtual environments to solve that problem. after a while I gave up and started to search for alternatives.
apparently virtual machines can't access GPU, only if you own a specif gpu type you can run the official NVIDIA visualizer.
I have a NVIDIA 1080 gpu. I installed a new image of Ubuntu 16.04 and started to work on dockerfiles to create custom images for my projects.

I was trying to avoid using docker to avoid complexity,after I failed in installing and running multiple versions of cuda I turned to docker. apparently you can't access cuda via docker directly if you don't install the cuda driver on the host machine. 
I'm still not sure if I could run docker containers with a different cuda version than the one I installed in my pc. 
if that is the case, NVIDIA messed up big time. usually if their is no need to use docker we avoid it to overcome additional complexities. when we need to work with multiple environments, and conda and virtual environment fail. we head out towards docker. so If nvidia limits the usage in docker container to one cuda version, they only intended to allow developers to work on one project of special dependencies per operating system.
**please confirm if I can run containers that each have a specific cuda versions.**

**Moreover I will greatly appreciate if someone point out to a guide on how to use conda enviroments to build docker files and how to run conda env in docker container.**

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're asking: provided you can run CUDA from inside Docker, then why not create multiple images, each with their specific CUDA version? Tag each image accordingly (e.g. include the CUDA version in the tag). I think confusion may be in the distinction between *image* and *container*. You run a container based on a given image. You build the images with whatever version of software you want, which will be executed when you run it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having several CUDA versions is possible with Docker. Moreover, none of them needs to be at your host machine, you can have CUDA in a container and that's IMO is the best place for it.

To enable GPU support in container and make use of CUDA in it you need to have all of these installed:

- [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/get-docker/)
- (optionally but recommended) [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install)
- [NVIDIA Container Toolkit](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker)
- [NVIDIA GPU Driver](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx)

Once you've obtained these you can simply grab one of the official [tensorflow](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated&name=gpu) images (if the built-in python version fit your needs), install pip packages and start working in minutes. CUDA is included in the container image, you don't need it on host machine.

Here's an example `docker-compose.yml` to start a container with `tensorflow-gpu`. All the container does is a test whether any of GPU devices available.

```yaml
version: "2.3"  # the only version where 'runtime' option is supported

services:
  test:
    image: tensorflow/tensorflow:2.3.0-gpu
    # Make Docker create the container with NVIDIA Container Toolkit
    # You don't need it if you set 'nvidia' as the default runtime in
    # daemon.json.
    runtime: nvidia
    # the lines below are here just to test that TF can see GPUs
    entrypoint:
      - /usr/local/bin/python
      - -c
    command:
      - "import tensorflow as tf; tf.test.is_gpu_available(cuda_only=False, min_cuda_compute_capability=None)"
```

Running this with `docker-compose up` you should see a line with GPU specs in it. It looks like this and appears at the end:

> test_1  | 2021-01-23 11:02:46.500189: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1402] Created TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0 with 1624 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1050, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)

Comment: you maid my day!!! thanks very much for your detailed explanation. I'm now following the instructions. I will report back when I finish the procedure.

Comment: yesterday I installed all the packages. when I installed the nvidia driver.
I downloaded the specific driver from offiicial nvidia page.
at first the driver would'nt install because of the x server. so I entered turned off the lightdm service and isntalled the driver. after installation my ubuntu is not logging in due to problems with the display driver. I am still trying to install a new version from terminal in shell command. wish me luck

Comment: @maryam_hallal the driver is the most difficult part. Read nvidia installation instructions carefully and good luck.

Comment: thanks very much. I was able to back up all the previous work. :)